# tkinter StringVar() AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am developing a Tkinter app. In the StringVar() part, It gets an Error:

> AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'tk'. Did you mean: '_tk'?

I've imported the module: `import tkinter as tk`

and here is the StringVar() part: (Error on line 2)

```py
games = ["Select Game", "Number Memory", "Reaction", "Game"]
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set(games[0])
game_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(var, *games)
```

For more information, Here is the full code and errors:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Game Launcher")
root.iconbitmap("app.ico")
root.geometry("800x400")
root.resizable(False, False)
title = tk.Label(text="Game Laucher", font=("Arial", 24))
title.pack()
title.place(x=10, y=10)
games = ["Select Game", "Number Memory", "Reaction", "Game"]
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set(games[0])
game_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(var, *games)
game_dropdown.pack()
game_dropdown.place(x=10, y=70)
root.mainloop()
```

```
PS D:\Test\Python\Game> py launcher.pyw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Test\Python\Game\launcher.pyw", line 13, in <module>
    game_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(var, *games)
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3991, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "menubutton", kw)
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2595, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2564, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'tk'. Did you mean: '_tk'?
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the first argument to `OptionMenu()` is supposed to be the parent widget object, not a StringVar.

Comment: Thank you! This has solved all the errors I've had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the `StringVar` object is not a `Tk` instance.

The wrong part is in the line:

```py
game_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(var, *games)
```

The first attribute should be the `parent` of the object(which should be a `Tk` instance), not a `StringVar`.

You can change that line to:

```py
game_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *games)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon), I've found an answer:

> The first argument to `OptionMenu()` should be the parent widget object